# How do I remotely view the screen of a PC that is playing a game?

Tags: pc, streaming

I like to talk my dad through games, but it can be difficult without seeing his screen. Is there any solution, such as a remote desktop-type product, that would allow me to "stream" his screen while in DirectX?

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a VNC program. However, the problem you will run into is that DirectX runs on the local hardware it is executed on. Therefore, it renders only on that particular computer's video card and monitor directly.

Are you both inside one network (wired) connection or in remote locations (or over wireless)? More bandwidth might be required for minimal slowdowns.

[UltraVNC](https://uvnc.com) uses the GPU for graphics processing, but it might not work particularly well depending on your system specs and the amount of action going on on the other side. Depending on the game you are running, you might need to disable "WinVNC video hook driver" (in your Device Manager under Display Adapters dropdown) on the computer hosting the VNC connection. If things are running too slow try reducing the color settings in UltraVNC.

Comment: I had always wondered why some games couldn't be seen through a Skype screen share!

Comment: Looks like xsplit may be the only all-in-one solution. It costs around $60/year which is a bit overkill for what I am doing but that cost seems to buy simplicity.

Comment: The's also Adobe's FMLE (Flash Media Live Recorder). In general, FMLE will allow you to tune more settings for a better result while X-Split is a lot easier to set up. What you are essentially asking for is live streaming (i.e. RTMP; e.g., how most ppl do live gameplay recordings). Can you describe the features that you are looking for (in terms of features and required level of setup desired)?

Answer (score 1):

If the game is on Steam and it supports Steam's [Remote Play Together](https://store.steampowered.com/remoteplay) feature, then you can use this feature to stream your dad's screen to yours and play together. [You can see the full list of games that support Remote Play Together here](https://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=44).

With Remote Play Together, one can host and run the game on their computer and invite up to four players — or more if they have a fast connection — to join them.

To start a session with Remote Play Together, follow these steps:

1. Launch any game that supports Remote Play Together.
2. Invite anyone from your friends list to play.
3. After they accept, they should now be able to see your screen, and you should be able to play together with them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible. You may be able to do something similar with OnLive.

https://superuser.com/questions/209023/is-it-possible-to-run-games-over-remote-desktop

Comment: From your link, one mentioned team viewer but I watched an example of a streamed game in teamviewer and it looked pretty terrible.